# On delete cascade for self-referencing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a comment table that is self-referencing.
I tried to write on delete cascade but it take some exception

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Comments_Comments' on table 'Comments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

and then try to write a trigger but it take exception again

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T_comment_Trigger]
    ON [dbo].[Comments]
    FOR DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM Comments
    WHERE ParentId =(SELECT deleted.id FROM deleted)
```

> couldn't delete rows that have children

how can I do on delete cascade for my self-referencing table?

Comment: It would really help if you *paid attention to* the error messages and *copied their text into the question*, rather than just saying "it take exception".

Comment: Your trigger has a major problem. It assumes there will only ever be a single row deleted. You need to use a join for this type of thing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I edit my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you're keeping your `FOREIGN KEY` constraint in place, you cannot fix the issue in a `FOR DELETE` trigger. `FOR` triggers (also known as `AFTER` triggers) fire *after* the activity has taken place. And a foreign key will *prevent* a row from being deleted if it has references. Foreign key checks occur *before* deletion.

What you need is an `INSTEAD OF` trigger. You also need to bear in mind that your current trigger only tried to deal with one "level" of referencing. (So, if row 3 references row 2 and row 2 references row 1, and you delete row 1, your trigger only tried to remove row 2)

So, something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T_comment_Trigger]
    ON [dbo].[Comments]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    ;WITH IDs as (
       select id from deleted
       union all
       select c.id
       from Comments c
              inner join
            IDs i
              on
                 c.ParentID = i.id
    )
    DELETE FROM Comments
    WHERE id in (select id from IDs);
```

If there are other (non-self-referencing) cascading foreign key constraints, they all have to be replaced by actions in this trigger. In such a case, I'd recommend introducing a table variable to hold the list of all IDs that will eventually be deleted from the `Comments` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T_comment_Trigger]
    ON [dbo].[Comments]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    declare @deletions table (ID varchar(7) not null);
    ;WITH IDs as (
       select id from deleted
       union all
       select c.id
       from Comments c
              inner join
            IDs i
              on
                 c.ParentID = i.id
    )
    insert into @deletions(ID)
    select ID from IDs

    -- Delete from FK referenced table
    DELETE FROM OtherTable
    WHERE CommentID in (select ID from @deletions)

    --This delete comes last
    DELETE FROM Comments
    WHERE id in (select ID from @deletions);
```

Comment: an error : **Cannot create INSTEAD OF DELETE or INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER 'T_comment_Trigger' on table 'dbo.Comments'. This is  because the table has a FOREIGN KEY with cascading DELETE or UPDATE.** occurs

Comment: @Mike - you need to remove *all* cascading foreign keys and implement all of the cascades manually inside this trigger. (You can still have the FKs, just not the cascade option)

Comment: **My table has `on cascade delete` for other foreign keys**

Comment: @Mike - yes, and you have to give that up. I've added an example of how you'd manually implement the cascade inside the same trigger.

Comment: is there any way except this way?

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever I came up with a [solution almost identical to the trigger you've shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185846/deleting-rows-recursively-in-a-self-referencing-table-using-a-cte-how-does-the), the problem is that  I don't get is why if I try to delete a comment, which have children, without the trigger I would get this error: The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint FK_Comment_Comment". The conflict occurred in database "X", table "dbo.Comment", column 'parent_comment_id'.

Comment: But if I do it inside the trigger no error is thrown. Let's say I have this hierarchy of comments: `3-> 8-> 13`, If I'm not mistaken, the first time a try to delete the comment of id 3, the CTE inside the trigger should return these ids: `3,8,13`, right? If so, the statement at the end of the trigger should look like this : `DELETE FROM Comment WHERE id IN (3,8,13)`. Why trying to execute this statement does not throw any referential integrity error?